# Outlook 2016 NOT asking for proxy creds

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

got an issue with outlook 2016 not displaying HTML linked images in e-mails.  I've checked all the usual options in the trust centre etc, but found the issue that it's hitting our proxy for the image, but its being denied because it's not asking for or sending credentials to the proxy.  I see a lot of posts about outlook and office asking too much for credentials, but i've got the exact opposite issue, it's not asking at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar article before，which mentioned if you are connecting to the Internet via a proxy server which requires basic authentication, then you’ll need to apply the latest updates to Outlook and configure the following Registry key:

Key : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office<version>\Common

Value name: AllowImageProxyAuth

Value type: REG_DWORD

Value: 2

Please check if it's your case, for more information, please refer to the Proxy Server with Basic Authentication part of this article [Internet images are not being downloaded in emails](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/588#:%7E:text=Proxy%20Server%20with%20Basic%20Authentication)

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly what the issue is, but unfortunately it didn't work.  I tried it with the value 1 and 2, but is still hasn't asked for proxy creds.  I can see it hitting the proxy, and it returning a 407 error.  It's happening to all the PCs here, so i'm guessing it's a group policy setting, but for the life of me, I can't find what it could be in there.  The policies were setup by someone else.